# Why was this reinforcement learning question migrated to AI.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

I noticed that this question

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10196/why-does-is-make-sense-to-normalize-rewards-per-episode-in-reinforcement-learnin

was migrated to AI.SE. [I think that it is perfectly on-topic here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/overlap-with-ai-stackexchange-and-datascience-stackexchange/5518#5518).

Did OP request the migration? Can anyone involved with the migration decision share their thinking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP flagged their question and requested migration.  I migrated it in response.

Comment: Perfectly fair! Thanks for clearing that up.