# What is the difference between crossvalidated and data science?

Tags: discussion, machine-learning

I often have to choose where to post a question and since Crossvalidated is present for a while, I stick with this site.
But is there any separataion?

Comment: Data Science is statistics on a Mac.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/data-science-se & https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/overlap-with-ai-stackexchange-and-datascience-stackexchange

Comment: what is "meta"?

Comment: @Ben https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @Ben This is a meta^2 question.