# Community conscious on viewing hot questions from artificial intelligence and data sciences stack exchange

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It is a well-known fact that overlap is high between the three sites: [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), [data sciences](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

If we go through the meta-questions of individual sites, we can also find a lot of differences based on what is on-topic on a particular site.

No one can deny that they are highly related or overlapped to each other. So, it is clear that the users, whether beginners, intermediates, or experts, can contribute to the three sites based on the questions asked. But it can be noticed that the users contributing to all three or at least two sites are rare.

The reasons I'm thinking are that the users either are interested in contributing to a single site or may be unaware of the questions on other sites.

The latter reason can be at least slightly fixed by streaming the hot questions on the other two sites somewhere on the main page of the third site.

It will provide users an advantage to read at least two to five hot questions on the other two sites so that they can diversify the contribution.

Do the members of the Cross Validated stack exchange welcome this feature?

Since I am sure that Artificial Intelligence community is ready to ask this feature, I asked [the same question](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/community-conscious-on-viewing-hot-questions-from-artificial-intelligence-and-cr) only on Data Sciences meta .

Comment: The question seems contradictory and based on assertion with no evidence whatsoever.  You say "overlap is high" but also that each site has different views about what is on-topic and that it is "rare" that users contribute to even two of these sites, let alone all.  So the question seems to be  a mix of a suggestion that people here may be missing out on interesting and useful threads elsewhere, yet asserting that, broadly speaking, active CV users appear indifferent to the other sites. There could be an element of truth in both, but the question seems confused to me.

Comment: Personally, I don't doubt that I am missing out on some useful threads. I don't mind anything being sent to Hot Network Questions, because I hardly ever look at them. No one else should care about my preferences, so see what anybody else says.

Comment: I don't understand what you're proposing, exactly. It has something to do with the overlap between DS.SE and stats.SE, but I don't know what you're trying to address and how you're trying to address it. Can you [edit] your post to clarify?

Comment: I am proposing a 'related network questions' stream on the main page, so that users can know that questions are asked on the related stack site and may increase the possibility of contributing to other related sites also.  @Sycorax

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Please note that anything that changes how the website software behaves is out of our hands -- that's done by the Stack Exchange company, not the individual websites. You might raise the question on the main meta site for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Sycorax They are asking the approval from all the three sites. So, I asked to know whether community is okay with such `hot related network questions` idea. If all the three communities accept to the idea, then I can post on Meta.

Comment: Can you link me to the main Meta page for that discussion?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366843/friendly-agreement-for-the-betterment-of-user-involvement-in-interest-intersecti) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/is-it-not-allowed-to-ask-a-question-regarding-multiple-sites-in-the-stack-exchan).

Comment: Perhaps related is that many users here don't feel like data science and AI SE should have been separate from CV anyway [1](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5518/176202), [2](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2253/176202). The AI SE for one came across like it was just made so a certain company could boast about sponsoring it.

Comment: (1) There's no chance that the company will add a new feature that affects only three sites (unless perhaps one of those is Stack Overflow). Your best bet is to write a general feature request on Meta SE, flesh it out a bit more than you have, & then post on the Metas of sites you think will be particularly interested. (Even then don't get your hopes up too much.) (2) Your SE Meta question was closed as a duplicate of a different proposal, viz to allow 'Related questions' - an algorithmically generated list relating to each specific post - to come from ...

Comment: ... other sites. You might want to edit it to clarify the difference. (3) See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads. If the trial goes well, you'll be able to pick questions from AI to promote across all sites on the network.